# Texmacs Icon is a stop sign when in dash

Tags: unity-dash

I installed the .deb package for Texmacs using Gdebi (which I downloaded straight from their website, since Ubuntu reps don't contain it). Everything works out except the Texmac's icon does not show up in the dash. How do I fix this issue ? Here is a photo :

[image]

Also, When I add texmacs to the dash and then launch it, it opens an extra texmacs instance at the bottom of the dash.

Comment: Could you please specify exact download link [from this (?) Texmacs page](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/download/linux-packages.en.html) and your Ubuntu version?

Comment: ftp://ftp.texmacs.org/TeXmacs/tmftp/Linux/xUbuntu_18.04/ Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by renaming my texmacs.desktop to texmacs.bin.desktop

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you find a fix?